# Recurring RecordNotFound error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

My index page doesn't show any of my posts (Named here fits)

However, after further troubleshooting, it appears that my posts aren't be created at all!

I tried adding a brand new post(fit) and it gives me a success message however my index doesn't display said post and after trying to navigate to /fits/X it gives me an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Error below)

```
Extracted source (around line #56):            
def set_fit
    @fit = Fit.find(params[:id])
end
```

my controller looks like this

```
def new
    @fit = current_user.fits.build
end

def create
    if @fit = current_user.fits.build(fit_params)
        flash[:success] = "Your fit has been created!"
        redirect_to fits_path
    else
        flash.now[:alert] = "Error adding fit! Please check fields."
        render :new
    end
end
```

and this is my model

```
class Fit < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates :user_id, presence: true
 validates :image, presence: true

 belongs_to :user

 has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy

 has_attached_file :image, styles: { :medium => "600x" }
 validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

I've also added this to my routes.rb. Could this be the issue? (Since no comments have been added yet)

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }  
 resources :fits do
   resources :comments
 end

 root 'fits#index'
end
```

I've been scratching my head at this for the past hour and am struggling to figure this out! Even though I'm confident it's something minor I'm just overlooking completely.

If you need access to anything else I've pushed it to github here for you. https://github.com/thgilartlU/MFID

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue is in your create method. You are not saving the record.  Create the variable and then make sure to save it.

```
def create
  @fit = current_user.fits.build(fit_params)
  if @fit.save
      flash[:success] = "Your fit has been created!"
      redirect_to fits_path
  else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Error adding fit! Please check fields."
      render :new
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I knew it was something minor I was overlooking.